# BigQuery load parquet file

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, parquet

I am trying to load a parquet type file into the bigquery table.

However, the date type column in the yyyy-mm-dd format is recognized as a String, and the following error occurs.

```
ERROR - Failed to execute task: 400 Provided Schema does not match Table my_prj.my_dataset.my_table. Field _P1 has changed type from DATE to STRING.
```

field_P1: 2022-10-05

Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution that comes to my mind is to load the data using Pandas library in Python. This way, you can convert string to related date format and load the data directly to BigQuery.